# Where to find Domain Driven Design consultants?

Tags: domain-driven-design

First of all, I don't know if this is the place to ask these sort of questions, but as I have yet to identify the proper forums and channels to look in, I'll resort to the experts here on SO.

My question is:

Here at work we're currently in the planning process of adapting our codebase to adhere to the principles of Domain Driven Design (DDD), and to that extent we've considered hiring in a DDD consultant to help us get started.

Does anyone here know of any DDD consultants, or where to go ask for them, if not here on SO?

We're a company based in Denmark, so the ideal is someone from Denmark, but if they are willing to travel, then that could be arranged as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SO has a jobs plataform designed specifically to hire people or get hired. I believe you or your company could hire people with the desired profile, inform how much you are going to pay, what place in the world your employee would have to work, but in order to do so you need to register yourself/yourselves in [here](https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/talent/platform/source/job-listings). You will also find more info in there.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I'll take a look at that :)

Comment: No problem! I'm sorry that i, myself, have not the exact knowledge of SO's policy of doing so. But if you think my answer was helpful, please accept it as a right answer :D